# Dynamic string formation in xslt based on xpath value

Tags: string, xslt, xpath, xquery

Can anyone suggest short and apt solution in xslt for below requirement.

I have below Xpaths which return 'Y' or 'N' as output.

```
us:user /ws:Additional_Information/ws:is_HR = 'Y'
us:user /ws:Additional_Information/ws:is_Manager = 'Y'
us:user /ws:Additional_Information/ws:is_Employee = 'Y'
us:user /ws:Additional_Information/ws:is_Admin= 'Y'
```

So, i need to form a string based above results as 'HR-Manager-Employee-Admin' as every other xpaths are returning 'Y'.

for suppose, if xpaths return output as

```
us:user /ws:Additional_Information/ws:is_HR = 'Y'
us:user /ws:Additional_Information/ws:is_Manager = 'Y'
us:user /ws:Additional_Information/ws:is_Employee = 'Y'
us:user /ws:Additional_Information/ws:is_Admin= 'N'
```

the string should be 'HR-Manager-Employee'.

And the process should satisfy all combinations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming XSLT 2 or 3 you can use

```
<xsl:value-of select="us:user/ws:Additional_Information/(ws:is_HR,ws:is_Manager,ws:is_Employee,ws:is_Admin)[. = 'Y']/substring(local-name(), 4)" separator="-"/>
```

or in pure XPath 2 or later

```
string-join(us:user/ws:Additional_Information/(ws:is_HR,ws:is_Manager,ws:is_Employee,ws:is_Admin)[. = 'Y']/substring(local-name(), 4), '-')
```

Comment: Thanks, Martin, It works like charm. In any way, can we control the order of the output string?

Comment: In 3.0 you can use the "!" operator: `string-join((us:user/ws:Additional_Information!(ws:is_HR,ws:is_Manager,ws:is_Employee,ws:is_Admin)[. = 'Y']!substring(local-name(), 4), '-')` to avoid it sorting into document order.

Comment: You should be able to use `for ... return` in XPath 2.0 e.g. `string-join(us:user/ws:Additional_Information/(for $c in (ws:is_HR,ws:is_Manager,ws:is_Employee,ws:is_Admin)[. = 'Y']) return substring(local-name($c), 4)), '-')`.